# How do I abbreviate journals for MDPI References?

Tags: bibliographies, mdpi

I'm planning on to submit an article to *Nanomaterials* in the coming days. I'm currently using the MDPI Overleaf Template. The MDPI Instructions for authors indicates that journal names in the references section should be abbreviated, but  the references are not abbreviated accordingly, as seen below:

[image]

Instead of *Microbes and infection*, *Microbes Infect.* should be displayed. Does anyone know how I can fix this directly from the Definitions folder in the Overleaf template? The files in the folder are `chicago2.bst`, `journalnames.tex`, `mdpi.bst`, and `mdpi.cls`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: MDPI is a predatory publisher. They famously published all the garbage “studies” about vaccines causing autism or being ineffective. Why they have been removed from Beall's list is inexplicable to me. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MDPI#Controversies

Answer (score 0):

You can leave the full journal names in the references. MDPI production editors have software to automatically abbreviate the journal names in the references, which will be applied as part of the production process if your paper gets accepted for publication.